# pronunciation of "böse" and "Börse"

Tags: pronunciation

So it's always struck me that the pronunciations for evil and Stock Exchange would seem to be almost identical.
Is this true?
Or am I missing something in the 'ör' of Börse that makes it sound different?

Comment: No, this is not true. They sound different ([ˈbøːzə] versus [ˈbœʁzə]). By the way, it's _b**ö**se_ and _B**ö**rse_.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Note there are dialects where it's pretty close for a non-native speaker - Namely the ones that pronounce "Kirche" as *Köache*.

Comment: If speaking High German there is a very clear difference IMHO.

Comment: It would be understood as friendly and polite if you took the effort to start your question with something a little bit more elaborate than "so".

Answer (score 8):

- böse = [ˈbøːzə]
- Börse = [ˈbœʁzə]

The vowel of the first syllable is different (long [øː] vs. short [œ]) although the two vowels are very similar.

More important:

- The first syllable of »böse« ends with a vowel. Immediately after the long [øː] the second syllable ([zə]) begins.
- In the first syllable of »Börse« there is the consonant [ʁ] after the vowel (and before the next syllable).

Note, that in German the consonants [ʁ]​, [r] and [​ʀ] are allophones, this means that each of them can be replaced with any of the two others. So also the pronunciations [ˈbœrzə] and [ˈbœʀzə] are valid.

Also note, that the letter r after a vowel often is spoken as a vowel itself (namely as [ɐ]) that is merged with the first vowel to a diphthong. So »Börse« is often spoken as [ˈbœɐ̯zə]. I even think that this might be the most frequent version.

Valid pronunciations of the German noun »Börse«:

- [ˈbœʁzə]
- [ˈbœrzə]
- [ˈbœʀzə]
- [ˈbœɐ̯zə]

---

Descriptions of the sounds used here:

**vowels**

- ɐ [Near-open central vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-open_central_vowel)
- ɘ [close-mid central unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_central_unrounded_vowel)
- ø [Close-mid front rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_rounded_vowel)
- œ [Open-mid front rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_rounded_vowel)

**consonants**

- b [voiced bilabial stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_bilabial_stop)
- r [voiced alveolar trill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_trills#Alveolar)
- ʀ [voiced uvular trill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uvular_trill#Voiced_uvular_trill)
- ʁ [voiced uvular fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_uvular_fricative)
- z [voiced alveolar fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_alveolar_fricative)

Comment: The r in Börse may become a vowel in some regions. Then is may sound almost like Böase, but still different from Böse.